# How to make sure that your files will be read on both linux/windows

Tags: java

I'm currently using this to read my files as inputStream, it works under windows, will this work in LINUX?

```
File file = new File(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath().toString() + "\\" + "myfile.txt");
```

If not what is the right way to read files, this "`\\`" looks kind of "fishy"

ADD-ON

I forgot this :

```
File currentDirectory = new File(".");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the filename separator, use `File.separator` there.

Better yet, use:

```
File file = new File(currentDirectory, "myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

actually "/" works on Windows too.